# c++ odd behaviour of an array of iterators

Tags: c++, arrays, iterator

So searching to see if someone has already asked this I see lots of questions about iterating over arrays.  But what I've got is an array of iterators.  Essentially here's what I'm up to:

I have a sorted std::list of a custom object.  The object just contains an int and a double, and has methods for the sorts of things you would expect (constructors, setters, getters, operator< to make it sortable by the double, a toSting() method).  That all works, including sorting.

Now I want a bunch of iterators that point into the list at different points.  There will be one to the head of the list, one to the tail and several pointing into various points in the middle.  I'm doing this using an old-style array (this may be the problem - I'll try it with a std::array, but I still want to understand why this hasn't worked).  So I've got a subroutine that initializes this array.  It almost works.  I can build the array and output from within the subroutine and everything looks good.  Outputting from outside the subroutine the last element of the array has changed and no longer appears to point into the list.  Here's the relevant code:

```
using namespace std;

#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include "random.h"
#include "Double_list_struct.h"

/**********************************Subroutine declarations***************************/

template <typename Tplt>
void output_list(list<Tplt> to_out);
template <typename Tplt>
void initialize_list(list<Tplt> &alist, int size);
template <typename Tplt>
void initialize_iter_array(typename list<Tplt>::iterator* itar, int size, list<Tplt> alist);

/***************************************Main routine*******************************/

int main(void)
{
  int list_size = 16;

  // Make the list that will be tested.
  list<Double_list_struct> list_to_play_with;

  initialize_list(list_to_play_with, list_size);

  list_to_play_with.sort();
  cout << "Sorted list is: " << endl;
  output_list(list_to_play_with);

  // Make an array of list<Double_list_struct>::iterator of size floor(sqrt(N))
  int iter_array_size = floor(sqrt(list_size));

  list<Double_list_struct>::iterator* iter_array;
  iter_array = new list<Double_list_struct>::iterator[iter_array_size];

  // Initialize the iterators in iter_array to point to roughly evenly spaced locations in the list

  initialize_iter_array(iter_array, iter_array_size, list_to_play_with);

  for (int i = 0; i < iter_array_size; i++)
    {
      cout << "In main routine, iter_array[" << i << "]:" << (*(iter_array[i])).toString() << endl;
    }

  cout << "Reset it, and redo the output loop??" << endl;
  iter_array[iter_array_size-1] = list_to_play_with.end();
  iter_array[iter_array_size-1]--;

  for (int i = 0; i < iter_array_size; i++)
    {
      cout << "In main routine, iter_array[" << i << "]:" << (*(iter_array[i])).toString() << endl;
    }    
}


/************************************************Subroutine code**************************************/

// Output all elements of a list to cout.

template <typename Tplt>
void output_list(list<Tplt> to_out)
{
...not important here
}


template <typename Tplt>
void initialize_list(list<Tplt> &alist, int size)
{
...not important here
}


template <typename Tplt>
void initialize_iter_array(typename list<Tplt>::iterator* itar, int size, list<Tplt> alist)
{
  itar[0] = alist.begin();
  itar[size-1] = alist.end();
  itar[size-1]--; // Recall that .end() makes an iterator point *past* the end...

  // Find out how big the list is
  int listsize = 0;
  for (typename list<Tplt>::iterator it = itar[0]; it != itar[size-1]; it++)
    {
      listsize = listsize + 1;
    }

  int spacing = floor(listsize/(size-1));

  cout << "In initialize_iter_array(): created itar[0]: " << (*itar[0]).toString() << endl;

  for (int i = 1; i < size-1 ; i++)
    {
      itar[i] = itar[i-1];

      for (int j = 0; j < spacing; j++)
    {
      itar[i]++;
    }
      cout << "In initialize_iter_array(): created itar[" << i << "]: " << (*itar[i]).toString() << endl;
    }

  cout << "In initialize_iter_array(): created itar[" << size-1 << "]: " << (*itar[size-1]).toString() << endl;
}
```

This generates output

```
Sorted list is: 
struct[15] = 0.135837
struct[1] = 0.200995
struct[12] = 0.217693
...SNIP...
struct[8] = 0.863816
struct[14] = 0.887851
struct[2] = 0.893622
struct[10] = 0.925875
In initialize_iter_array(): created itar[0]: struct[15] = 0.135837
In initialize_iter_array(): created itar[1]: struct[5] = 0.314127
In initialize_iter_array(): created itar[2]: struct[11] = 0.704419
In initialize_iter_array(): created itar[3]: struct[10] = 0.925875
In main routine, iter_array[0]:struct[15] = 0.135837
In main routine, iter_array[1]:struct[5] = 0.314127
In main routine, iter_array[2]:struct[11] = 0.704419
In main routine, iter_array[3]:struct[-1] = 6.21551e-71
Reset it, and redo the output loop??
In main routine, iter_array[0]:struct[15] = 0.135837
In main routine, iter_array[1]:struct[5] = 0.314127
In main routine, iter_array[2]:struct[11] = 0.704419
In main routine, iter_array[3]:struct[10] = 0.925875
```

So, you see, `iter_array[3]` is correct inside the initialization subroutine, but has "moved" after the subroutine exits.  I then reset it from outside the subroutine, but obviously I'd like to not have to do that...

My best guess is that there is something subtle going on here with how the assignment operator works for iterators.  But I'm very puzzled.

Comment: Typically, you do not want to store iterators for later use.  There is the potential that operations can invalidate them, and you would be attempting to dereference elements that no longer exist.

Comment: Thanks!  The thing I'm trying to build would give me persistent "pointers" into the linked list as a way of speeding up searches.  So it is at least conceptually similar to a hash table (which I'm in the process of learning about).  In the old days when I learned this stuff we would have just used pointers to do this.  But obviously pointers are frowned upon these days since they are unsafe.  So I had thought to do it with iterators.  What sort of object would suggest for persistent links into the middle of the list?

Comment: Pointers and iterators are no more "unsafe" than the other.  The key is how they are being used.  Just like a pointer, an iterator is invalidated anytime the list changes the underlying memory (which can happen in a variety of ways).  Having the array sorted would allow you to speed up searches, but unless the list is large, this is likely to be a micro-optimization.

Comment: OK, so what I'm hearing is that I just have to be very careful about how the array of pointers or iterators is managed so that as members of the list are deleted the array elements aren't invalidated.  I think I've got that under control.  The list will be of order 10^4 or 10^5 elements.  It will repeatedly have the head element removed and a new element generated and inserted at the correct location.  This will happen of order 10^8 times, so I think the speedup from finding the insertion point faster than iterating along the list should be large.

Comment: It sounds like a list of objects is not really going to help you as you'll be allocating and deallocating a LOT of data.  It may be more helpful to create a list of shared pointers.  At least then, you will only be allocating and deallocating memory for the pointer (instead of your actual objects).

Comment: Each list element that is removed gets destroyed.  Then the a new one is randomly generated and inserted into the list at the correct place.  So I don't think I can get around allocating and deallocating memory.  The objects themselves are small.  I chose a linked list because insertions are fast, and now I'm trying to make the finding of the insertion points fast.  Are you suggesting that I not keep the data sorted and that I just maintain a list of pointers that are used to store the ordering information?  Wouldn't this mean that at each insertion I'd have to rewrite a lot of pointers?

Comment: I was under the assumption that you were "moving" elements (removing it from one location and adding it to another).  A `std::deque` would make your insertions a little slower, but would make your access much faster.

Comment: Yup, that was one of the options I was considering.  deque vs. list.  I may still go with the deque option but I'm seeing if I can make the access in the list fast enough that I'll have the best of both worlds.  As I understand it insertion in a deque is O(n) but access is O(1).  In a list insertion is O(1) but access is O(n).  So if I can just construct a way to cut the access time in the list down to O(log(n)) or even O(sqrt(n)) then the list wins.

Comment: Since a list doesn't really have random access capability, you are kind of stuck.  Insertion for a deque is only O(n) when inserting somewhere in the middle - it is O(1) when inserting (or removing) at either end.  Since your removal always happens at the end (if I understand you correctly), you lose nothing there.  Another alternative would be to use a hashing container (`std::set`, `std::map`, or `std::multimap`).  That would probably be the "best of both worlds" alternative you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`initialize_iter_array` takes the list by value, which means it's putting iterators that point into the parameter copy of the list, not the original list. You probably meant to pass the list by `const&` instead.

Comment: Ha ha!  Yes, passing by value rather than by reference is exactly the problem.'initialize_iter_array(..., list<Tplt> *alist)' works perfectly.